# VLCJ RTP Streaming client side

Tags: java, streaming, rtp, vlcj

I am doing a project that is based on VLCJ streaming. I have looked up the the VLCJ tutorial on how to create the server side from the below code. How would the client get the video content from the server? I have written the client code as well but it's not displaying anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Server code:

```
package com.khalid.VideoStreaming;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.headless.HeadlessMediaPlayer;


public class PublicServer extends VlcjTest{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Specify a single MRL to stream");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String media = args[0];
    //String publicIP = "192.168.0.255";
    String publicIP = "192.168.1.104";
    short publicPort = 5555;
    String options = formatRtpStream(publicIP, publicPort);

    System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options, ":no-sout-rtp-sap", ":no-sout-standard-sap", ":sout-all", ":sout-keep");

    Thread.currentThread().join(); // Don't exit
}

private static String formatRtpStream(String serverAddress, short serverPort) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);
    //sb.append(":sout=#transcode{acodec=mp4a,samplerate=12000,width=400,height=300}:rtp{dst=");
    //sb.append("::sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,scale=1,fps=30,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,width=800,height=600}:rtp:duplicate{dst=file{dst=");
    sb.append("::sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=3000,fps=30,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=48000,width=800,height=600}:rtp{dst=");

    sb.append(serverAddress);
    sb.append(",port=");
    sb.append(serverPort);
    sb.append(",mux=ts}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Client side:

```
String mediatorIP = "192.168.1.104"; short mediatorPort = 6001;
String publicIP, publicServer, localIP, localServer, clientIP;
short publicPort, localPort;

MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);
mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

JFrame f = new JFrame();
//f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(Client.class.getResource("icons/vlcj-logo.png")).getImage());
f.add(canvas);
f.setSize(800, 600);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
publicIP = inFromServer.readLine(); // Recv public server's ip from mediator
publicPort = Short.parseShort(inFromServer.readLine()); // Recv public server's port from mediator
publicServer = formatRtpStream(publicIP, publicPort);
System.out.println("Capturing from '" + publicServer + "'");
f.setTitle("Capturing from Public Server 'rtp://" + publicIP + ":" + publicPort + "'");
mediaPlayer.playMedia(publicServer);
```

As you can see above, mediaPlayer.playMedia(publicServer) should be displaying the video contents but nothing is displayed. The JFrame is just empty.

Comment: What is the actual MRL you are playing in your client?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. Than actual MRL in my client is rtp://@192.168.1.104:55555. I ran the client from another computer and it gave me this error: "open of 'rtp://@192.168.1.104:55555' failed." and VLC is unable to open the MRL "rtp://@192.168.1.104:55555". Any suggestions, Please. Thank you.

Comment: Your original question has 5555 as the "public" port, not 55555 as per your comment.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. The port number is 5555. Using the VLC software to stream does not have any problem. However, running my server program and then the client does create that problem I mentioned. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know. The streaming client and server examples in the vlcj test sources all work for me.

Comment: The matter has been resolved. Apparently the problem was the private IP address. When I changed the IP the multicast (e.g. 230.0.0.1 as in your examples), it worked fine. Thanks anyway. VLCJ is a great framework.

Comment: @khalidcawl Does your client side code works for any RTP flux ? Or only the one that your server send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had with the code shown above was the IP address of the server. The client would connect to the server but VLC wouldn't play the MRL. So I did a bit of research on caprica's examples online and found that I should use a multicast IP address to stream with RTP. (e.g. 230.0.0.1) and the problem got resolved. Streaming from the client side occurred without problem.